# Setting Gregorian Calendar But Not Getting Correct Day of Week

Tags: java

In part of my program, I am manipulating the Gregorian Calendar by setting the date to what the user specifies. I am able to print the correct month, day, and year, but it is not showing the correct day of the week. Could someone please point out what is going on?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class MyCalendar {

    GregorianCalendar calendar;
    private HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash;
    GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
    static DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();

    MyCalendar(){
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        myCalHash = new HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event>();
    }

    public HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> getMyCalHash(){
        return myCalHash;
    }

    public void setMyCalHash(HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash) {
        this.myCalHash = myCalHash;
    }

    public void viewCalendar() {

            System.out.print("[D]ay view or [M]view? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'D'){ dayView(); }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){ monthView(); }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }
    }   

        public void dayView(){
            //print day calendar
            //GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today

            System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] 
                    + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            System.out.print("[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                dayView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                dayView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }
        public void monthView(){
            //print month calendar
            int formatCounter = 0;
            dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
            }//print days of week

            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                    System.out.print("   ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 1; i < dayCounter.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
                if(formatCounter == 7){
                    System.out.println();
                    formatCounter = 0; //reset counter
                }
                dayCounter.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
                if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) <= 9){
                    System.out.print(" " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }


            }

            System.out.print("\n[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                monthView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                monthView();
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }


    public void goTo(){
        System.out.print("Enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format: ");
        String userDate = sc.nextLine();
        String[] dateArr = userDate.split("/");
           calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
           calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]));
           calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

           System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  
           arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

  //more stuff

    }



}
```

Edit:
DAYS is an enum defined in a testerClass as follows:

```
    enum DAYS
{
    Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa;
}
```

Sample output:
If user enters today's date (03/12/2015)
Program should print:
Th, March 12, 2015
But program is printing:
Su, March 12, 2015

Another edit
Here is how my months are defined in an enum:

```
enum MONTHS
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;
}
```

Comment: it's better to show only the problematic and related codes instead of showing the whole code of class, sorry for not reading the code and question all.

Comment: What does the definition of `DAYS` look like? Can you provide an example of your expected and actual output?

Comment: @RyanJ I have updated my original post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Bollinger's answer points out the reason why you're seeing this anomaly, due to the fact that the months are 0-based, not 1-based, and your `goTo` method is setting the date incorrectly.

There's a couple issues here, that are giving you the false impression that you've set something up correctly everywhere except the day of week.

First:

```
calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]));
```

You parse the user input and set the month of the calendar based on the user value (aka 03 for "March").

However, as John has pointed out, the month numbers are 0-based, so the calendar thinks 3 is "April".

This is all well and good for your lookup, as you're properly getting the day of week (Sunday), but for the wrong month (April), on day 12 in 2015.

Your lookup from the array though is properly giving you the impression that the Month is set right because you're using the *Calendar's* value for the month (which is 0 based).

You are incorrectly subtracting 1 from this value to look up the Month name, which makes you think that the day of week is wrong.

You need to fix two places (lookup and set):

```
calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0])-1);
calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  
arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar` month numbers are zero-based, so for instance, `Calendar.MARCH == 2`.  Your `goTo()` method does not account for that, and as a result, it sets the calendar to the wrong month.

**Update**:

It looks like you want this:

```
public void goTo(){
    System.out.print("Enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format: ");
    String userDate = sc.nextLine();
    String[] dateArr = userDate.split("/");

    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]) - 1);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

    System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", "
            + arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " "
            + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", "
            + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But it prints the month, day, and year correct every time. Even if I change to a different month (April, February, etc). It only chokes on determining which day of the week it is.

Comment: @aurora91 He's saying your error is here `calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]));`. You set the month of the calendar to the value parsed from the user entered month, which should be 0-based, not 1-based. You're setting the calendar to an effective month of April, which in fact, has day 12 on a Sunday in 2015. You're echoing the correct Month because you correctly use the -1 when looking up the value from your array, but the calendar internals think it's really April.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to determine why it echoes back the month correctly, as that is modulated by array `arrayOfMonths`.  It echoes back the year and day of the month correctly because you set them correctly.  The calendar just returns the month number you set in it, though, so correct month output just indicates that your output technique decodes the calendar value the same (wrong) way the input technique encodes it.

Comment: @RyanJ Ah, ok I think I'm starting to understand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated my post to include the enum for arrayOfMonths. But I think I might be able to figure it out from here. Thank you for the help!